# Guardar los valores de un for a un arrayy mostrarlo en un input

Tags: angular, typescript

Buenas tardes tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un ciclo for el cual obtengo, hago un recorrido e imprimo unos correos, hasta ahí todo bien, el detalle es que quiero mostrar todos los correos que obtengo en un input, pero solo me muestra 1 el cual es el último.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
openDialogEnviarCorreosMasivos() {
this.dialogEnviarCorreosMasivos = true;
for (let correos of this.selectedInstitucions) {
  //console.log(correos)
  this.m_ecm_correos_seleccionados = correos.correo_institucion;
  console.log(this.m_ecm_correos_seleccionados) 
}
console.log(this.m_ecm_correos_seleccionados)
```

}

y lo quiero mostrar en un input con el ngmodel m_ecm_correos_seleccionados pero no me sale esa parte.

```
 <div class="field col-12 md:col-12">
                    <label class="font-bold">Correos selecionados</label>
                    <p-chips placeholder="Correos seleccionados" separator="," [(ngModel)]="m_ecm_correos_seleccionados" placeholder=""></p-chips>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el loop lo que estás haciendo es sobrescribir el valor de la propiedad `m_ecm_correos_seleccionados` en cada iteración. Por eso al final el valor que te queda es el del correo del último elemento.

Lo que tienes que hacer es crear un nuevo array y guardar en el todos los correos.

Usando el `for...of` loop sería algo así:

```
const correosSeleccionados = []; // iniciamos un nuevo array

for (let correos of this.selectedInstitucions) {
  correosSeleccionados.push(correos.correo_institucion); // añadimos al array el correo de cada elemento
}

this.m_ecm_correos_seleccionados = correosSeleccionados; // asignamos el array generado a la propiedad
```

Tambíen puedes hacerlo de manera más compacta usando directamente el método `map` sobre el array de seleccionados, indicando en su función de mapeo con que te quieres quedar de cada elemento.

```
this.m_ecm_correos_seleccionados = this.selectedInstitucions.map((institucion) => institucion.correo_institucion);
```

un saludo